# How can I resize a UITableView header?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uiview

```
self.headerView.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 167); //this is a UIView
```

doesnt seem to do anything. everything is hooked up in IB.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i need to call setHeaderView after defining the frame.

Answer (score 0):

is this in a UITableViewController? if so, try accessing the tableHeaderView (`self.tableView.headerTableView`) and then getting the subview you want.

Comment: can i adjust the height on self.tableView.headerTableView? if not, how can I get a subview inside of it?

Comment: headerTableView is not a property of a tableView

Answer (score 0):

Try the UITableViewDelegate's `-(CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` method.

Also, the `-(UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section` might also be of interest to you if you're trying to put a custom view as a header.